# Installing Docker during AWS CodeBuild

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

When running a bash script during CodeBuild, I get this error:

`./scripts/test.sh: line 95: docker: command not found`

However, I've made sure to install docker at the start of the script using:

```sh
curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh
apt-get install -y docker-ce docker-compose
```

But this results in the following error:

```
Package docker-ce is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'docker-ce' has no installation candidate
```

Any ideas on how to get `docker` working during CodeBuild?

Answer (score 3):

There are a few different options for this in CodeBuild:

1. You can use CodeBuild provided images, which will already have docker installed on them. To use any one of these images select the privilege mode when creating the CodeBuild project.
2. You can enable Docker in custom image (images not managed by CodeBuild. e.g.: hosted in your ECR repo or public DockerHub) when configuring CodeBuild project. Select the privileged mode for your project settings. Instructions here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-docker-custom-image.html

Comment: This does not work for me. I get `nohup: failed to run command '/usr/local/bin/dockerd': No such file or directory`

Comment: @KakaRuto you need to install the docker on the custom image. The AWS doc starts with a pre-installed docker. One way of doing it on ubuntu stackoverflow.com/a/59175554 (will need to change the path to /usr/sbin/dockerd as well.